# IIS 6 Rewrite rule, hide directory

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-10

Say I have domain: [www.test.com](http://www.test.com) and I want to internally in the server redirect this to localhost:3000/folder1/

I then make a rewrite rue

```
<rule name="Kofferslot" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(test\.com|www\.test\.com)(.*)" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:3000/folder1/{C:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Now in the addressbar if I go to `test.com` it changes to `test.com/folder1`. How can I keep that folder hidden and in the internal rewrite only?

Comment: Do you mean it worked when you requested `www.test.com`, but now you need it to work when you request `www.test.com/folder1`? if so, you only need to change the pattern from `(.*)` to `^$|folder1`, this will satisfy both requested urls.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should learn how to use your web browser to troubleshoot such issues.

1. Open developer tools and switch to Network tab (Chrome/Edge).
2. Reproduce the issue and see what requests/responses are captured.

Based on the rule and behavior you described above, it is not hard to reconstruct the scene,

- The browser asks for `http://test.com`.
- IIS rewrite rule takes effect and rewrites the request to `http://localhost:3000/folder1/` (that's how `{C:2}` is resolved).
- **Something in your web app dislikes the ending `/`, so it generates a 30x redirection to `/folder1`.**

By then, your browser ends up with `http://test.com/folder1`.

Thus, you currently have two options,

- Locate and disable the redirection logic inside the web app.
- Or if that's not possible, revise your rewrite rule to always ignore ending `/`.